PyMC model from aggregated data
I am starting with probabilistic programming and PyMC and seems that stuck with the first step. I am trying to figure out something very simple and then add complexity. Appreciate if you can help me and guide in right direction.
Let say there is aggregated data for patients broken down by gender and two cancer diagnoses:



diagnosis
gender
number




lung cancer
male
1000


lung cancer
female
800


breast cancer
female
1600


breast cancer
male
200



I am trying to build a statistical model for this distribution and later use it to answer questions such as “according to the model, with 95% confidence how many there are lung cancer patients among N (let say 100) [randomly chosen] male patients?”
The model and question is very primitive, but I am trying to figure out generic solution which can be used for large aggregated dataset with many dimensions and various questions

see binomial regression example.you need to collect what amount didnt get cancer https://www.pymc.io/projects/examples/en/latest/generalized_linear_models/GLM-binomial-regression.html

You're missing the denominator (total male / female population) to be able to answer your question, regardless of the statistical approach you're interested in.
